# Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting. (Meteor 1.4.3.1)

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, meteor

I'm just trying to get into Meteor.js, so I'm still unexperimented on the subject. Following a tutorial about Meteor, I get an error message in the command prompt on the command "meteor": **Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.**

I searched a lot on Internet for a solution. I tried "**meteor reset**", I can't delete the **.meteor/local/db/mongodb.lock** file because there is not any file in the **db** folder, and restarting my computer didn't change anything. I tried to start my Meteor.js project on my two computers, one running on **Windows 10** and the other on **Windows 7**. Both have the same issue. Also, my **Meteor version is 1.4.3.1**.

Here is what the console returns:

```
D:\Meteor\Test>meteor
[[[[[ ~\D\Meteor\Test ]]]]]
=> Started proxy.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Unexpected mongo exit code 100. Restarting.
Can't start Mongo server.
MongoDB had an unspecified uncaught exception.
This can be caused by MongoDB being unable to write to a local database.
Check that you have permissions to write to .meteor/local. MongoDB does
not support filesystems like NFS that do not allow file locking."
```

I'm running out of ideas. Do you have any solution that may have worked on your side?

Comment: "I can't delete the `.meteor/local/db/mongodb.lock` file because there is not any file in the db folder" - sounds like you found your problem.

Comment: Try creating a new meteor project and see if it will start.

Comment: @rbellamy "sounds like you found your problem"
So, what would be the solution to that?

Comment: @jordanwillis "Try creating a new meteor project and see if it will start."
I tried this more than once... :(

Comment: Could you post a GitHub link to your project, then I'll take a look at it.

Comment: @jordanwillis Thank you : https://github.com/JonathanLauzon/first-meteor-project

Comment: Ill take a look.

Comment: @JonathanLauzon I was able to run your meteor project with no issue (though there was nothing in it...just the vanilla project generated when you run `meteor create <app>`).  I'm not sure why it is not working for you.

Comment: @jordanwillis I'm pretty sure that the error is related to the system, but how to know? I tried on my two computers running on Windows 7 and Windows 10.